# Showing image from database in DataGridView

Tags: c#

I have small problem but I need your help.  I have successfully inserted pictures into the DB therefore, I am trying to access those images through `DataGridView`.  Whenever I click `dgv` row/cell I need the picture(s) to appear in the picture box.  here is my code.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Candidates WHERE CandidateID = '" + dataGridViewCandidate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
//dataGridViewCandidate.DataSource = dt;
byte[] binaryimage = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][1];
Bitmap image;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(binaryimage))
{
    image = new Bitmap(stream);
}
EmployeePhoto.Image = image;
```

The error I am getting is below;

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't specify a `DateTime` type anywhere. Where does the error occur?

Comment: I know that is what I confused

Comment: `(byte[])dt.Rows[0][1];` I suspect that you use the wrong column.

Comment: byte[] binaryimage = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][1]; Image it converts to byte and store column name

Comment: I checked the column data type and it has varbinary(MAX).  I did not use image because I was advised it will be removed from SQL Server in future

Comment: Make sure that you check the second column of the `DataTable`.

Comment: What DataTable? I think I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you put it inside a picturebox

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Image FROM tableName",yourConnectionStringHere);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.fill(ds);
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
     data = (Byte[])(dr["ImageColumnName"]);
    MemoryStream ms= new MemoryStream(data);
    yourPictureBoxID.Image= Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```